# Find reason long running stored proc SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, profiler

I have a stored proc which is called every 2.5 seconds by a program, 24-7.
This proc normally runs under the 10 milliseconds. A few times a day (3 -5 times) it takes around 42953 milliseconds to run (always between 42950 and 42959 milliseconds).

How can I find or profile the reason why it takes so long?

**Update:**
Sql server version 2008 R2

Procedure:

```
select 
    [view_EventsToRaise].EventId,
    [view_EventsToRaise].EventStatus,
    [view_EventsToRaise].Tag,
    [view_EventsToRaise].SessieGebruikerId,
    Postbus.Persoon_Id_afz      as PersoonIdAfz,
    Postbus.Persoon_Id_adr      as PersoonIdAdr,
    Postbus.Persoon_Id_derde    as PersoonIdDerde,
    Postbus.Locatie_Id          as LocatieId,
    Postbus.Artikel_Id          as ArtikelId,
    Postbus.Onderwerp_Id        as OnderwerpId,
    Postbus.Bedrijf_Id_afz      as BedrijfIdAfz,
    Postbus.Bedrijf_Id_adr      as BedrijfIdAdr,
    Postbus.Bedrijf_Id_derde    as BedrijfIdDerde,
    Postbus.Document_Id         as DocumentId,      
    Postbus.Document            as Document,        
    DataKenmerk.Code            as PostbusDataCode,
    PostbusData.Inhoud          as PostbusDataInhoud,
    SimObj.Id                   as SimObjId,
    Eventsoort.Code             as Eventsoort
from 
    [view_EventsToRaise]
    left outer join Postbus
        left outer join PostbusData
            inner join DataKenmerk
            on PostbusData.DataKenmerk_id = DataKenmerk.id
        on PostbusData.Postbus_Id = Postbus.id
    on Postbus.Id = [view_EventsToRaise].PostbusId
    left outer join SimObjEvent                         
        inner join eventsoort
        on eventsoort.id = SimObjEvent.eventsoort_id
    on [view_EventsToRaise].SimObjEventId = SimObjEvent.Id
    left outer join SimObj
    on SimObj.Id = SimObjEvent.SimObj_Id
order by
    [view_EventsToRaise].Tijd,
    [view_EventsToRaise].EventId
```

**Update 29-9-2014:**
When the above described situation occurs, looking to the profiler, the following got mine attention:
When the RPC:Completed event is registered, the the starttime is the current system time at the log moment, but the endtime is a value in the future (current system time plus the duration, approx. 43 sec in the future).

*How is the value of the endtime column determined? 
Is this a prediction?*

Comment: Can you post the stored procedure up? We may be able to find the cause there. Also, if it is being hit every 2-3 seconds, the likelyhood is probably a lock on a table

Comment: What version of SQL server?

Comment: I have never seen joins written like that before!

Comment: Execution plan? You can pull latest [deadlocks from `system_health`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/deadlock/65658/) session.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably caused by a blocking process. 3-5 times a day this is blocked by some update or other write that takes ~40 seconds. Your SELECT blocks until it can continue. If this is indeed the case, the problem can be identified using the [Blocked Process Report Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191168.aspx). You will have to enable this event and set the threshold to ~35 seconds. See [blocked process threshold Server Configuration Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181150.aspx). Obviously the event may fire for other queries too, but arguable those issues also needs to be addressed.

A simple workaround for blocking is using a row versioned isolation level. [Read Understanding Row Versioning-Based Isolation Levels](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189050(v=sql.105).aspx).

Otherwise, you will need to investigate this as a performance problem. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).

Comment: I used [this artikel](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/how-to-identify-blocking-problems-with-sql-profiler/) for finding the problem. I configured the threshold at 35 sec and using the profiler I started a new trace (blank template) with only the Blocked process report. Unfortunately nothing was logged. Any other suggestions?